# Removing white-space between nav-bar items

Tags: css

My navbar is based off an un-ordered list.

```
Each <li> is displayed as inline-block.
```

However I am unable to get rid of the white-space between the li's

```
nav-item li{
  width: 123px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I have researched this item on stackoverflow/google but haven't found an solution yet.

Plnkr here:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/7irazgvxqkpCeurnQ0Yv
```

Comment: change `display: inline-block` to `float: left`

Comment: please put this in the answers so I can mark it so..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 0):

Change `display: inline-block;` to `float: left;`:

```
nav-item li{
      width: 123px;
      height: 120px;
      float: left;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the white space and line breaks in your HTML between the LIs.

```
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li><li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li><li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: normal;` to your nav-item class

```
.nav-item li{
  width: 123px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 white-space: normal;
}
```